# Formatting cells in excel worksheet with multi conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

What I want to do is format 1 cell lets say A1 (change it background color if 3 conditions is true) I mean `&&` should be beetwen this condicions.

I have success but only with single condition.

Example:

1 of my column has numbers from 1 to 7 and if this number is different than 3 and 6 and 7 then change background color of cell.

`=$A$1<>"3" && $A$1<>"6" && $A$1<>"7"` doesn't work so is it possible?

When I add 3 different conditions it's split with `or (||)`.

So is there a way to do that?

Hope my problem is clear enough:)

Thanks in advanced:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I remember well, there is no "&&" or "||" in Excel formula. You probably can use "OR" and "AND" keywords instead. Using the "conditional formatting" menu, you must select "Formula is" instead of "Value is" in the drop down menu. Then, you can use any complex Excel formula (OR, AND, TRUE, ...)

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

```
=IF(AND(A1<>3,A1<>6,A1<>7),TRUE,FALSE)
```

### Bonus 1 - Flexible conditions

To make logic easy to change, consider putting them in a separate cell D1 as "3, 6, 7", then change conditional formatting formula to:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(A1,$D$1)),TRUE,FALSE)
```

[image]

This also helps with Excel's limitation on how many logic evaluations you can have within and() or() not() in the same formula. I've hit it before but can't remember exactly how many. Perhaps others can shred some light.

### Bonus 2 - To use or not to use absolute reference?

You can check multiple cells against A1's value by using absolute reference $A$1:

[image]

But if you want to check multiple cells against their own value, select the multiple cells with A1 as starting point, then don't use absolute references:

[image]

Similarly, to check another column against their respective row counterparts in column A, use $A1:

[image]

Note that Excel is particular about the starting point of "Applies to" region. If you use conditional formatting formula evaluating against A1, you must have A1 as the beginning of "Applies to" region:

[image]